# WorksheetFunction.Subtotal method throws error in C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Getting Error when using subtotal in C#

```
//Referencing
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetFunction xlWsf;

    //declaring a range

    xlRangeDB = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1000");

    //declaring a double variable
    double numVal = 0;

    //using subtoal function but throws error!!!
    numVal = xlWsf.Subtotal(3,xlRangeDB);
```

Can anyone help why I am getting error.
Microsoft link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.subtotal.aspx

Comment: For future reference, don't just tell us you're "getting error". Error messages are *useful* things - even if you're unable to interpret them, often would be answers would be able to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetFunction xlWsf = xlApp.WorksheetFunction;
```

The only problem was not initiating variable.